# Finding/Counting Duplicate Values in Array in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am new to the mongo database. Using Robo3t software
I have to find out duplicate values inside an array based on **channel_id**.
I did a research and found that aggregation needs to be used to do grouping and find respective count.
I have developed the following query but results are not as expected.

**Sample Documents:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59b674d141b47e5401897d31"),
    "subscribed_channels" : [ 
        {
            "channel_id" : "1001",
            "channel_name" : "StarPlus",
            "channelPrice":"100"
        }, 
        {
            "channel_id" : "1002",
            "channel_name" : "StarGold",
            "channelPrice":"75"
        }, 
        {
            "channel_id" : "1001",
            "channel_name" : "StarPlus",
            "channelPrice":"100"
        },
        {
            "channel_id" : "1003",
            "channel_name" : "SetMax",
            "channelPrice":"80"
        }
    ],
    "viewer_account_id" : "59b6745b41b47e5401143b3d",
    "public_id_type" : "PHONE_NUMBER",
    "viewer_id" : "+919322264403",
    "role" : "CONSUMER",
    "active" : true,
    "date_time_created" : NumberLong(1505129681330),
    "date_time_modified" : NumberLong(1569320824387)
}

{
        "_id" : ObjectId("59b674d141b47e5401897d31"),
        "subscribed_channels" : [ 
            {
                "channel_id" : "1001",
                "channel_name" : "StarPlus",
                "channelPrice":"100"
            }, 
            {
                "channel_id" : "1002",
                "channel_name" : "StarGold",
                "channelPrice":"75"
            }, 
            {
                "channel_id" : "1001",
                "channel_name" : "StarPlus",
                "channelPrice":"100"
            },
             {
                "channel_id" : "1001",
                "channel_name" : "StarPlus",
                "channelPrice":"100"
            }
        ],
        "viewer_account_id" : "59b6745b41b47e5401143c56",
        "public_id_type" : "PHONE_NUMBER",
        "viewer_id" : "+919322264404",
        "role" : "CONSUMER",
        "active" : true,
        "date_time_created" : NumberLong(1505129681330),
        "date_time_modified" : NumberLong(1569320824387)
    }
```

Above are just 2 records of document viewers

**Query :**

```
db.getCollection('viewers').aggregate([ 
        {
                    "$group" : 
                    {_id:{
                        //viewer_id:"$consumer_id",
                        enterprise_id:"$subscribed_channels.channel_id",
                         }, 
                         "viewer_id": {
                             $first: "$viewer_id"
                        },
                        count:{$sum:1}
                        }},

                        {
                          "$match": {"count": { "$gt": 1 }}
                        }
                 ])
```

**Actual Output :**

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "enterprise_id" : [ 
            "1001", 
            "1001", 
            "1002",
            "1003"
        ]
    },
    "consumer_id" : "+919322264403",
    "count" : 2.0
}
{
    "_id" : {
        "enterprise_id" : [ 
            "1001", 
            "1002", 
            "1001",
            "1001
        ]
    },
    "consumer_id" : "+919322264404",
    "count" : 2.0
}
```

**Expected Output :**

I want to group based on **subscribed_channels.channel_id** and get a count respectively

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "enterprise_id" : [ 
            "1001", 
            "1001", 
            "1002",
            "1003"
        ]
    },
    "consumer_id" : "+919322264403",
    "count" : 2.0
}
{
    "_id" : {
        "enterprise_id" : [ 
            "1001", 
            "1001", 
            "1001",
            "1002
        ]
    },
    "consumer_id" : "+919322264404",
    "count" : 3.0
}
```

Grouping is not happening based on channel_id, also the count is incorrect.
  The count is not even giving me no of channel-id subscribed, also not giving duplicate channel_ids.

Please guide me in building a query that gives the correct result.

Comment: So if you want duplicates first doc will have 1 & second will have 2, If I'm not wrong is that correct or what you've given is right ? Cause in 1st doc `["1001", 
            "1002",
            "1003"]` will be unique only duplicate is another `1001`.. Then if you've this `[
      "1002",
      "1002",
      "1001",
      "1001"
    ]` do you consider it as 4 duplicates ?

Comment: Hi @whoami. Thank you for replying. i want results as per documents. 1st doc would give count as 2 since there are two 1001 and 2nd doc should give count as 3 since there are three 1001. Also as per your understanding if i get first doc giving 1 & second doc giving 2 it will work.Please let me know if any other clarifications are needed, i will update my question

Comment: Hi @whoami. I want to highlight documents which contain duplicates based on channel_id . Can you give me a head start for query ?

Comment: I feel giving count as 1 for 1st & 2 for 2nd is perfect which is correct cause those are the no.of elements duplicated (Also if you just need docs which has duplicates you don't need count, Is that your actual question ? Or do you want all docs & a added field(some field like hasDups : true) for those docs which has duplicates ?)

Comment: @whoami , Yes thank for your suggestion. Yes you are right count as 1 for 1st and 2 for second is perfect and would suit my requirement as i would know which channel_ids are repeated within a document. Also a added field will also suffice but option1 looks more prominent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below query :

**Query :**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  /** project only needed fields & transform fields as you like */
  {
    $project: {
      customer_id: "$viewer_id",
      enterprise_id: "$subscribed_channels.channel_id",
      count: {
        /** Subtract size of original array & newly formed array which has unique values to get count of duplicates */
        $subtract: [
          {
            $size: "$subscribed_channels.channel_id" // get size of original array
          },
          {
            $size: {
              $setUnion: ["$subscribed_channels.channel_id", []] // This will give you an array with unique elements & get size of it
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-zTF-nb_0SF)

Comment: hi @whoami . executing the above query gives error as   Error: command failed: {
 "ok" : 0,
 "errmsg" : "The argument to $size must be an array, but was of type: missing",
 "code" : 17124,
 "codeName" : "Location17124"
} : aggregate failed . are my documents corrupt ?

Comment: @AjinkyaKarode : Yes, I think some of your docs doesn't have subscribed_channels as array. Can you see if that's correct ? What do you wanted to do on those ?

Comment: hi @whoami Sorry, i just verified all documents and yes in some docs there is no subscribed_channel field since that viewer has no subscription. How can i handle such docs ?

Comment: @AjinkyaKarode : what do you've to do to those docs ? Do you want to remove those from result ?

Comment: @AjinkyaKarode : Ok all you need to do is to filter those out using `$match`, try this `{
    $match: {
      subscribed_channels: {
        $type: "array"
      }
    }
  }` or test it here :: https://mongoplayground.net/p/Ds57XGvVp6p

Comment: Thanks a lot brother @whoami , It worked. Just one last help I need only those results which has count more than 1 , because i am getting results with count as -1,-2. Also i ll try to search this on internet . Your command over mongodb is excellent , Do you have any tutorials for such complex mongodb queries? I will pay for them if needed

Comment: @AjinkyaKarode : :-) Ok going back to my initial question Do you need docs that has duplicates ? Or Do you need docs that has duplicates along with count ? Redg. tutorials you can find those here :: https://university.mongodb.com (Free & directly from Mongo)

Comment: Just verfied the output, i have not got any docs with count greater than 0.

Comment: @AjinkyaKarode :What is the issue ? What has differed from test playground ?

Comment: Hi @whoami .Thanks for all your efforts,Just verfied the output. https://mongoplayground.net/p/GxtKlE0fkst  and i got count more than 0. I ll check out the website you recommended, but also if i want to learn from you is it possible?any email id or linkedin?

Comment: @AjinkyaKarode : Yes if you want docs with dups, you can use another `$match` at end & filter docs with count >0

Comment: @AjinkyaKarode : Nope even I'm kind of new, started MongoDB over an year, So you should probably in same stage within no time, unfortunately I'm not in a level to teach, but certainly can help if I can, you can ping me in SOF :-) al d bst..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209866/discussion-between-ajinkya-karode-and-whoami).

Comment: hi @whoami , university of mongodb has Introductory course on aggregation. Should i take udemy courses on MongoDB for advanced concepts